# What is the connection of a sigmoid with probability?

Tags: probability

In high school probabilities for an event are the chance of an event to happen. The easiest is a coin with 1/2 for each event.

I've been reading about Machine Learning and [sigmoid functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function), and it seems sigmoid has something to do with probability.

I've noticed the derivative is a Bell-like curve, and sure enough the integral of bell curves is normally a sigmoid.

But apart from being between 0 and 1 I see no real connection to a probability.

Any hints or useful places to get started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sigmoid function $\sigma(u) = \frac{e^u}{1 + e^u}$ is useful in machine learning because it converts a real number into a probability (that is, just a number between $0$ and $1$). If you try to come up with the simplest possible differentiable function that does this job for us, I don't think you can find anything much simpler or more elegant than the sigmoid function. One of the elegant properties of the sigmoid function is that $\sigma'(u) = \sigma(u)(1 - \sigma(u))$.

When doing binary classification (with two classes called class $0$ and class $1$), we want to find a prediction function $f$ that takes a feature vector $x$ as input and returns as output a probability that an example described by this feature vector belongs to class $1$. We use the sigmoid function to force the output of $f$ to be between $0$ and $1$ so that it can be interpreted as a probability.

---

By the way, another elegant property of the sigmoid function is that it "plays well" with the cross-entropy loss function $\ell(p,q) = -p\log(q) - (1 - p) \log(1 - q)$, which is used in machine learning to measure how well a probability $q$ agrees with another probability $p$. Notice that if $0 \leq p \leq 1$ then the function $L(u) = \ell(p, \sigma(u))$ satisfies
\begin{align}
L(u) &= \ell(p, \sigma(u)) \\
&= -p \log\left(\frac{e^u}{1 + e^u} \right) - (1 - p) \log\left( 1 - \frac{e^u}{1 + e^u} \right) \\
&= -p \log\left(\frac{e^u}{1 + e^u} \right) + (1-p) \log\left(1 + e^u \right) \\
&= -pu + \log(1 + e^u) .
\end{align}
Look how much that simplified! Beautiful.
It follows that
\begin{align}
L'(u) &= \sigma(u) - p.
\end{align}
That's a beautiful and simple result. When using gradient descent to train a logistic regression model, the iteration is very simple and intuitive thanks to the simplicity of this result.

Comment: 1/(1-x)  positive Xs ? But so there is nothing conceptual, right?

Comment: Hmm what do you mean by $1/(1-x)$?

Comment: that function seems to be similar and simpler? P(0)=1, P(inf)=0. And it should be $1/(1+x)$. But this was just a random thought. I mean, how are we interpreting probabilities here? Isn't different conceptually to what I learnt in high school? How do you make sense of it?

Comment: $1/(1 + x)$ is not defined at $x = -1$.  Another nice function is $x \mapsto (1/\pi)\arctan(x)  + 1/2$.

Comment: Oh I see. Well, we want a function whose input can be any real number, either positive or negative, and whose output is guaranteed to be between $0$ and $1$. You could try to adjust your function by replacing $x$ with $e^{-x}$, which is guaranteed to be positive, but then you've rediscovered the sigmoid function.

Comment: thank you for completing

Comment: (It occurs to me that it might be helpful to add that one thing that makes the logistic / sigmoid function nicer than my [candidate](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/8227626) is that it satisfies the nicer autonomous differential equation $y' = y(1 - y)$, as opposed to $y' = (1/\pi)/(1 + \tan(\pi (y - 1/2))^2)$.  This is closely related to the elegant property now mentioned at the end of this answer.)